# Running Number Of EF Is Circle?

Tags: entity-framework

> When I Add Entity to the table, ef give auto number `1` to the entity
>
> And After That I remove the entity  and after that i add the Same
>
> Entity Again Ef Give Auto Number `2` My Question Is What Happen When
>
> Entity Reach The max number of the key Var Ef Start again from 1 if
>
> Its Available Or i will get error?

Comment: Please reword your question and make sure that you encapsulate all the requirements.

Comment: And add some punctuation.